# What are these old Chinese books?

Tags: china

While cleaning my house i found some old books written in Chinese. Can anybody tell me what these are? What the books are about and do they have any historical significance?

If this post does not fit into History and to any other SE site please migrate it.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

[image: Image 5]
[image: Image 6]

Comment: I believe that those items are Japanese, because of the presence of kana characters.

Answer (score 4):

These don't look like books (although they may have been bound that way); instead they are newspaper clippings. As Aaron points out, they are in Japanese not Chinese. I don't see any dates on the images but from the kanji used it looks post-simplification of Japanese characters (which happened 1946).